# Implementing reactive templates in golang

Tags: javascript, templates, go, reactive-programming, go-templates

I'm coming to Go from Meteor.js, which, while full of awesome features, is a little too black-box-y for my taste. One of the awesome things about Meteor was blaze, which made their templating engine reactive; database changes were propagated to the UI immediately.

In Go, though, no such solution seems to exist, aside from maybe trying to integrate React. Is there a good way of making Go's templates (things like {{range}} and stuff) reactive, so that they respond to database changes instantly?

What we have right now, for context, is something like this (in JS):

```
$(".delete-button").click(function (e) {
    obj = $(this).closest(".object");
    id = $(obj).data("id");
    $("[data-id=" + id + "]").hide();

    // try to delete the element from the table
    database.delete(id, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            $("[data-id=" + id + "]").show();
            log(err);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

This is fine, but it's kind of frustrating for more nuanced things, like editing. Any ideas or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: As I know meteor is not one app, it contains of different components. The server side engine is node and the reactive part is vue.js. You can not compare Go and meteor.js, because you also can not compare meteor and node.js, because node.js is just one part of meteor. To achieve a reactive template in Go like meteor you could use vue.js with gorilla/websocket and mongoDB. If you search you will easyly find some boilerplates for different architectures.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't confuse rendering templates on server side with running code in the browser and modifying the DOM. The only way to update the rendered template is to refresh whole page, unless you inject some JS code there.

Answer (score 0):

Worth taking a look at [Hugo](http://gohugo.io/).

It's a static site generator written in go which which supports [LiveReload](https://gohugo.io/extras/livereload/), as you've described. It's lightening fast.